# define debug using Unicode Character Set

Tags: windows, direct3d

I'm following a book called "Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 9.0c: A Shader Approach" and all the example there are using **Multi-Byte Character Set** and I don't want to  use it and I don't want my project to be in multi-bye chacters. My problem is there is a debug function on the book here is the code.

```
//debug
#if defined(DEBUG) | defined(_DEBUG)
    #ifndef HR
    #define HR(x)                                      \
    {                                                  \
        HRESULT hr = x;                                \
        if(FAILED(hr))                                 \
        {                                              \
            DXTrace(__FILE__, __LINE__, hr, #x, TRUE); \
        }                                              \
    }
    #endif

#else
    #ifndef HR
    #define HR(x) x;
    #endif
#endif
```

then on my .cpp files i used this code on the book to create device.

```
HR(md3dObject->CreateDevice(
        D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, // primary adapter
        mDevType,           // device type
        mhMainWnd,          // window associated with device
        devBehaviorFlags,   // vertex processing
        &md3dPP,            // present parameters
        &gd3dDevice));      // return created device
```

then the error is. **error C2664: 'DXTraceW' : cannot convert parameter 4 from 'const char [107]' to 'const WCHAR *'**

hope someone can help me. thx.

Comment: This book is teaching you more than one bad practice.  A CreateDevice() failure must end the program.  Get rid of the book.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the parameter from `#x` to `L#x`, or use Microsoft's macro `_T(#x)`.